# getting libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER when we restart the server

Tags: centos

I have a centOS 8 server.
Today when I restart it, it got following errors in the journalctl:

```
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2631]: libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open nouveau: /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_video_caps_info (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2631]: libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open nouveau: /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_video_caps_info (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2631]: MESA-LOADER: failed to open nouveau: /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_video_caps_info (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2631]: failed to load driver: nouveau
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2631]: MESA-LOADER: failed to open kms_swrast: /usr/lib64/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_video_caps_info (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2631]: failed to load driver: kms_swrast
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2631]: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_video_caps_info (search paths /usr/lib64/dri)
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2631]: failed to load swrast driver
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 gnome-shell[2631]: Failed to create backend: Failed to initialize renderer: Failed to create gbm device: No such file or directory, EGL is not initialized, or could not be initialized, for the specified EGL display connection.
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 gnome-session[2614]: gnome-session-binary[2614]: WARNING: App ‘org.gnome.Shell.desktop’ exited with code 1
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 gnome-session-binary[2614]: WARNING: App ‘org.gnome.Shell.desktop’ exited with code 1
Jun 23 13:05:23 ebchko01 gnome-session-binary[2614]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
```

And then, the server's monitor cannot display anything.
I didn't touch any library.
How can I debug this?
Thank you guys.

Tried to restart the server again. hoped it would go away. but the same issue kept coming up